# pytesseract has bad performance on digits

Tags: ocr, signal-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract, digits

I have the following image which I want to parse to '4/1/3' with pytesseract.

[image]

The result I get is '4/13\n'.

[image]

When using a grayscale image, the performance is slightly better from experience. For this image, I get '4/113\n'.

The code I am using is:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/', lang='eng')
```

I set the flag --psm 8 to tread it as a single word, and I specified a whitelist of only digits and '/'.

Are there other options I should use to increase the performance of tesseract in this case?

Comment: So do you have a problem with tesseract performance or OCR quality? If the latter one is right - did you try to read the tesseract documentation?

Comment: The OCR quality is worse than I expected, and I already applied all fitting options I found in the documentation.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by fitting options. Providing real information and details would help (e.g. tesseract version, tessdata version, the original input image...). Also keep in mind that tesseract was trained on word sentences, so nonword OCR could be tricky.

Comment: I meant the parameters of the image_to_string method, in my case I used config='--psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/', lang='eng'

Comment: As mentioned earlier - please post the original image you use (what you post has a scale that indicates it is not what you pass to pytesseract. Also make sure you read and tried suggestions from [the tesseract doc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md)

Comment: This is the image I passed into tesseract. Stackoverflow shows it in a pretty big size, but it is actually just ~ 30x50 pixels

Comment: So you expect that we will resize it back??? You need help - you must provide the necessary inputs for reproducing the problem.